# How can I store all values in localstorage so that it doesn't reset after every click?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm trying to store all the `likedUserIds`s and `dislikedUserIds`s in local storage but for some reason, it's not even hitting the `if()` statement.  The `likedPhotoUserId` function parameter indeed has a value, so why's it not hitting the first `if()`?

Any feedback would be appreciated!

```
const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    console.log(likedPhotoUserId); // value is present

        // dislike

        if(likedPhotoUserId) {
            // if the user id exists
            if(localStorage.getItem('dislikedUserIds')) {
                console.log("inside if");
                // split the existing values into an array
                let vals = localStorage.getItem('dislikedUserIds').split(',');

                // if the value has not already been added
                if (!vals.includes(likedPhotoUserId)) {

                    // add the value to the array
                    vals.push(likedPhotoUserId);

                    // sort the array
                    vals.sort();

                    // join the values into a delimeted string and store it
                    localStorage.setItem('dislikedUserIds', vals.join(','));
                } else {
                    console.log("inside else");
                    // the key doesn't exist yet, add it and the new value
                    localStorage.setItem('dislikedUserIds', likedPhotoUserId);
                }
            }
        } else {

        // like

        if(likedPhotoUserId) {
            // if the user id exists
            if(localStorage.getItem('likedUserIds')) {
                console.log("inside if");
                // split the existing values into an array
                let vals = localStorage.getItem('likedUserIds').split(',');

                // if the value has not already been added
                if (!vals.includes(likedPhotoUserId)) {

                    // add the value to the array
                    vals.push(likedPhotoUserId);

                    // sort the array
                    vals.sort();

                    // join the values into a delimeted string and store it
                    localStorage.setItem('likedUserIds', vals.join(','));
                } else {
                    console.log("inside else");
                    // the key doesn't exist yet, add it and the new value
                    localStorage.setItem('likedUserIds', likedPhotoUserId);
                }
            }
        }

    }

};
```

Comment: The code doesn't reach the _first_ if statement, above the first `localStorage.getItem`? Is the value of `likedPhotoUserId` `0`?

Comment: @ZacAnger it's a string value

Comment: Why there there is an `if ` wrapping the same evaluated `likedPhotoUserId` inside your `else`?

Comment: @Alvin brain fog, haha.  Been hacking away at this for quite some time now, I've hit a wall

Comment: @Alvin made the change but I'm still experiencing the same wrongful behavior, not sure what else to do

Comment: I'm a little confused by the whole function. You're also adding to both liked photos and disliked photos, on the same click, without a parameter or anything indicating which the user intended.

Comment: @ZacAnger yeah I honestly am confused as well.  I've been looking at this for too long.  Pretty much exhausted all of my options and attempts.  Not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: The first `else` looks like it should be connected to `if(localStorage.getItem…` and not `if (!vals.includes…`

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand, you could do this in a more readable way:

```js
function likeOrDislike(likedPhotoId) {
    // Get value or define empty
    const likedStored = localStorage.getItem("likedIds") || "[]";
    // Convert string into array
    let likedArray = JSON.parse(likedStored);
    
    // Check if exists or not
    if (likedArray.includes(likedPhotoId)) {
        // Remove from array
        likedArray = likedArray.filter(
            (photo) => photo !== likedPhotoId
        );
    } else {
        // Add to Array
        likedArray.push(likedPhotoId);
    }
    // Convert to string to store in localStorage
    const stringLiked = JSON.stringify(likedArray);
    localStorage.setItem("likedIds", stringLiked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the logic in your code, but I'm pretty sure this satisfies your use-case. The issue with your code never hitting the first condition is particularly confusing because that doesn't happen in my test.

```
// when repeating strings in code, it's useful to set them
// as variables so your autocomplete and linter can help you out
const likedStorageKey = 'likedUserIds'
const dislikedStorageKey = 'dislikedUserIds'

// using JSON is a little easier than manually building and splitting the list
const storageListOrDefault = (key) =>
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || []

const setStorageItem = (key, list) =>
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(list))

// if an item is in the list, remove it
const removeFromOppositeList = (storageKey, toRemove) => {
  const vals = storageListOrDefault(storageKey)
  setStorageItem(storageKey, vals.filter((id) => id !== toRemove))
}

const toggleInList = (storageKey, toAdd) => {
  const vals = storageListOrDefault(storageKey)
  // here we filter the old list, assuming you want your like/dislike
  // buttons to have a 'neutral' state.
  // if the array already includes the item and you're toggling to a neutral
  // state, we remove the id
  // if the list doesn't include the id, we concat the id to the array, and sort
  const newList = vals.includes(toAdd)
    ? vals.filter((x) => x === toAdd)
    : [...vals, toAdd].sort()
  setStorageItem(storageKey, newList)
}

// onClick functions for your like and dislike buttons
const handleLike = (id) => {
  if (id) {
    removeFromOppositeList(dislikedStorageKey, id)
    toggleInList(likedStorageKey, id)
  }
}

const handleDislike = (id) => {
  if (id) {
    removeFromOppositeList(likedStorageKey, id)
    toggleInList(dislikedStorageKey, id)
  }
}
```

Performance note: none of this is particularly efficient, but if you're worried about performance I would recommend using a library that's designed for this sort of state management with persistence.